# if two columns contain specific text, return true in separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue with coming up with a formula for excel that returns true in a column if two columns before it contain a specific word.

For example,
If Column A and Column B contain "Snow Valley" and "Rain Valley", then Column C returns "TRUE"  only if both A AND B contain "Valley"

Does anybody know of an efficient method to do this? Thank you.

Comment: or `=COUNTIFs(A1,"*Valley*",B1,"*Valley*")>0` for _contains_ "Valley"

Comment: only if the two columns contain the words "Valley"

Comment: see my updated comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this works:

`=COUNTIFs(A1,"*Valley*",B1,"*Valley*")>0`

Answer (score 1):

```
=not(or(iserr(find("valley",B1)),iserr(find("valley",C1))))
```

Find() returns #VALUE! If it does not find any match, which explains why i need the iserr(). Iserr() will be True if nomatch and I do Or() to catch the True if any of the two Match() did not contain the word valley. So the Not() makes the True/false behave like you want.

Comment: I dont have a function that recognizes INSTR ? I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: Sorry, I was in VBA. Thats where it exists. In the worksheet it is Find() or Search()